# catalog rule not applied at product page but working at checkout page

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

Yesterday I added a catalog price rule of 20 % discount for one of my categories but the catalog rule is only working at checkout, the discounted price is not get reflected on the product list page, I am running Magento commerce on my mobile, I have designed an android app to run this Magento commerce from one of the development company but the company is saying catalog rules are only applied at checkout times
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show screenshots from the Rule itself. There are two types of rules - Cart Rules, Catalog Rules. Cart rules apply in cart, Catalog Rules apply on Product Pages / Catalog Pages / Widgets. I would assume you are seeing Cart Rules applied instead of Catalog Rules. Please check which section the rule exists in.

Comment: No, I am in Catalog Rule, I am fully aware of cart rule but I am talking here of catalog rule